# Place an image over another image

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I am developing a web site. For this I want to place an image over another image. I will explain.

Start a td which have `width: 1101px`. Here I placed an image with img tag (logo of my web site). Width of image is `1101px` on the left topside of the image (over the image) I want to place another image. It's not possible to place the logo image as background, because it must have alt tag. I know the div method with absolute position. But it's not a good solution. While changing the resolution it’s (top image) alignment is not constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to do it...

```
<td>
<div style="position:relative;">
<img style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;" />
</div>
</td>
```

The resolution won't mess this up.. The image is absolute, `only relative` to the div..

it should work, without any problems :)

is what you currently have similar to this?